# How to keep spaces in the formatted expression in jqMath

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmath

I am using [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) for Math equation formatter. I don't want to remove spaces and newline character from the expression. How can I do that? I have tried a lot but I coudn't find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the author ...

> In general, it's best to let html handle the text, and jqMath handle
>   the math.  For example, write " using $y = (x+1)/(x+2)$", or "<td>$x+y
>   = 2$<td>(1)" inside an html table.
>
> You have to be able to separate user input into mathematics and
>   non-mathematics.  If a user inputs "using y=x" you don't want "using"
>   parsed as the product of 5 variables u, s, i, n, and g.  Similarly, if
>   he inputs extra spaces that you want to keep outside the mathematics,
>   you have to capture them using regular expressions or something, and
>   don't pass them to jqMath.  If you want the spaces to be part of the
>   mathematics, you could make the user input \table or \sp or \text or
>   something, though most users won't know to do that.  You could tell
>   users that they need to put $ $ around their mathematics if they want
>   it to format, and then you could search for that.
>
> Basically, jqMath isn't smart enough to tell what's math and what
>   isn't, without $ $ to help.
>
> Probably 0.2.0 will be out in a couple months, or at least I'll have a
>   version I could send you by then.

**Update :** New version is out which support /text and /html

Answer (score 1):

Using \text and "" is used to give space inside the formula

**HTML source :** [\text"average speed" = \text"distance traveled" / \text"elapsed time"] 
**Result** : [image]

this example is available in http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html

Answer (score 1):

Update: If you stumble on this, jqmath has added `\,` `\:` and `\;` operaters that specify thin, mid, and thicker white spacing.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it can be done.  To quote the page you provided:

> spaces, tabs and newlines are ignored - jqMath formats the mathematics

Comment: yes it says so.but i have to keep these spaces.so if any small change or any tweak possible to keep spaces ?

Comment: example of "way to keep spaces " : No,
example of "what i want  " is :s2mathE("x+a  y+b") should result in "x+a   y+b " not like "x+ay+b"