# In jqmath, Integration symbol is very small. How to make it larger

Tags: jqmath

In jqmath integration symbol is very small. How to make it larger.

∫ dx  = x + C

Answer (score 0):

What browser and operating system are you using? This depends on those, and your installed fonts. For me (Chrome on an iMac) jqMath produces: [image: jqMath output]. In Chrome if I right-click on the output integral sign and choose Inspect, I see it's

`<mo class="fm-large-op fm-prefix">∫</mo>`

and the rule in line 70 of jqmath-0.4.3.css gives:

```
.fm-large-op {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

which makes the symbol large.

Comment: Thank you Dave.... It is working. I am using chrome. Could you please tell me how to make space between two expression in jqmath.

Comment: I got the answer here for making space between two expressions. Thank you once again....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601222/how-to-keep-spaces-in-the-formatted-expression-in-jqmath